# React hooks, function components and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

React hooks makes it possible to use all React features such as component state and lifecycle methods without class declarations (just function components). This reduces boilerplate, duplication and negotiates the use of bug-prone `this` keyword. Further it makes it easy to isolate and share common state-management logic across unrelated components, thanks to function composition.

However, hooks doesn't replace Redux by it's purpose of centralized and predictable state container. Is it possible to connect React function components to Redux, as I want to embrace the functions only paradigm of future React and still use Redux?

Comment: Hooks should not be comparable to redux. You _could_ make a comparison between react context and redux, but even there are some big difference. You _can_ use hooks to interact with redux. react-redux provide hooks api from v7.

Comment: "Hooks should not be comparable to redux". That's what I said. Thanks, I will check out the react-redux hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Is it possible to connect React function components to Redux?

**yes, it is possible**, there is no difference. Simple example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Foo = ({ bar, handleOnClick }) => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
      {foo}
      <div>{bar}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  bar: state.bar
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleOnClick() {
    dispatch({ type: "foo" });
  }
});

export const FooContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Foo);
```

Actually, you can see that in the Redux documentation intself:

- functional component definition - https://redux.js.org/basics/example#components-todolistjs
- container - https://redux.js.org/basics/example#containers-visibletodolistjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks introduced in `react-redux` v7.1 as a stable release. 
Here's the link: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks